# Can I construct std::vector with zero elements via the non-default constructor

Tags: c++

I mean something like this:

```
std::vector<T> v(0);
```

Is it ok? I don't see any requirements like this in the Standard.

Comment: There's more than one non-default constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is well-defined. The standard does not place any restrictions on the value of `n` passed to this constructor. `0` is a valid value of type `size_type` (whatever that is).

Comment: The standard specifies `size_type` to be an unsigned integer type.  In reality this is `unsigned long` (at least for `stdlibc++`).

Comment: @henri: implementation defined. Msvc in 64 bits mode doesn't, as it would limit the container size to 4 billion.